# MySQL table groups or separate database?

Tags: mysql, installation

I did some looking around did not see what I was looking for.

I cannot add new databases without using my hosts admin panel. I want to store data separate per 'group' using the database (branch North, branch West, etc).

I'm not sure if I should allow my application to create new tables for each group (North_users, West_users) approx 15 tables per group, approx 50 groups.

or...

Create a new database per group. This would slow the sign-up process by 2-3 days for the new group.

Certainly I could do a table for the group (like users, but group id)and mingle all records, but I'm not sure what MySQL can hold and be efficient/fast/stable... I'm a newbie in that regard.

So multiple databases? Separate tables? Or one database with group id's?

Answer (score 2):

I'd go for one database with group id's. You won't have to modify your table structure when a new group is added, and the number of tables stays within limits. With separate tables or a separate database, you will need to make any modification 50 times.

MySQL is quite good, but it depends on what you do with it. Hundreds of heavy used connections may slow your database down, as will lots of simultaneous writes. Also, you don't want to put 20 million records in a single table that is used a lot.

But for regular use, this is by far the best (easiest and most maintable) option.

In case of problems you can always decide to split the larger tables, but even that should be a last resort.